# Remove Drupal Login Link

Tags: 7, users, blocks

I'm trying to remove the login link from the Drupal site.

However, despite the User login being set to none. It still shows on the site.

Is there a way to hide the link?

Thank you,
Kevin Davis

Comment: What do you mean by "set to none"? You just have to uncheck the *enabled* in the line of "Log Out" in **Administration** -> **Structure** -> **Menus** -> **User account menu**. Maybe empty the cache after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a login block that you need to disable. 
structure > blocks disable the login block.